# Ruby DSL Initialization of Variables

Tags: ruby, sinatra, dsl

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of Sinatra.  Specifically the DSL-like part where you can define routes in the definition of the class.  When I try to run my version of a persons-DSL I get the error, `undefined method '<<' for nil:NilClass` on line 11.

```
class Persons
  class << self
    def reset!
      @persons = []
    end

    def add_person title, name
      @persons << {
        title: title,
        name: name
      }
    end
  end

  reset!
end

class MyPersons < Persons
  add_person 'Dr.', 'Bob'
  add_person 'Mr.', 'Jones'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good nights sleep and some more Googling, I have come up with the answer.  There appears to be a `#inherited` method in Ruby; that is called when a class is inherited (duh).

Actually, this is how Sinatra implements instance variables in `Sinatra::Base`.

```
class Persons
  class << self
    def reset!
      @persons = []
    end

    def add_person title, name
      @persons << {
        title: title,
        name: name
      }
    end

    def inherited child
      child.reset!
    end
  end
end

class MyPersons < Persons
  add_person 'Dr.', 'Bob'
  add_person 'Mr.', 'Jones'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You are never initializing `@persons` to anything other than nil. A simple fix would be

```
class MyPersons < Persons
  reset!
  add_person 'Dr.', 'Bob'
  add_person 'Mr.', 'Jones'
end
```

The reason your call to `reset!` doesn't work is because `MyPersons` and `Persons` do not share the same `@persons` variable.

You can use `@@persons` instead to share the variable. Your example would look like this instead:

```
class Persons
  @@persons = []
  class << self
    def reset!
      @@persons = []
    end

    def add_person title, name
      @@persons << { title: title, name: name }
    end
  end
end

class MyPersons < Persons
  add_person 'Dr.', 'Bob'
  add_person 'Mr.', 'Jones'
end
```

Comment: The second part is my question.  How could I initialize `persons` without having to call a method in the child classes?